# Efficient JPA @oneToMany relationships

Tags: performance, jpa, one-to-many

I have a project where the database schema is under our control. We are using JPA2 (currently Eclipselink, but going to move over to Hibernate so that we can use the Audit envers framework) on a MySQL database.

The issue that I have is that the application that we are writing depends on often repeated queries across 3 entities that are related through 3 @OneToMany relationships. The resulting join across these 3 entities (and the 2 joining tables) is encountering deadlock issues and I am trying to work out how to address these (I think the inefficiency of the join across the 5 tables is the cause).

Can anyone advise if a restructure of the @OneToMany relationships would be appropriate so that there are no joining tables would make for better performance of the join query in a JPA setting? I believe that in JPA2 you can set the mappedBy parameter on the parent object to point to a field on the child object that mimics the standard way of expressing a 1 to many relationship where the child has a FK pointing back to the parent.

However I have found a reference to this approach not being the best from a JPA point of view.

Has anyone got experience with this situation that they could share?

Comment: Without the schema of your DB it is hard to say if it could be improved. Ofcourse less tables in a query is easier for the DB. BTW could it be that you are using myisam tables i'm no expert on mysql but afaik myisam has very course locks leading to locking problems using innodb may greatly reduce locking issues.

Comment: When using `OneToMany` or `ManyToOne` you don't need to use a join table. Only when using `ManyToMany` you need to use a join table. I'd strongly suggest using innodb engine for several reasons.